# Create a new array of arrays from multiple CSV files data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a React app in which I want to upload multiple CSV files and create an array out of them. I want them to be in the below format.

Currently, I see the output as:

```
[
 {"Name":"user 1","Age":"12","Rank":"2"},
 {"Name":"user 2","Age":"13","Rank":"3"},
 {"Name":"user 3","Age":"10","Rank":"2"},
 {"Name":"user 4","Age":"16","Rank":"1"},
 {"Name":"user 5","Age":"14","Rank":"5"},
 {"Name":"user 6","Age":"11","Rank":""}
]
```

and

```
[
 {"Name":"Person 1","Age":"27","Rank":"6"}, 
 {"Name":"Person 2","Age":"32","Rank":"3"},
 {"Name":"Person 3","Age":"25","Rank":"2"},
 {"Name":"Person 4","Age":"31","Rank":"4"},
 {"Name":"Person 5","Age":"22","Rank":"1"},
 {"Name":"Person 6","Age":"29","Rank":""}
]
```

But I want the output as

```
[
 [
  {"Name":"user 1","Age":"12","Rank":"2"},
  {"Name":"user 2","Age":"13","Rank":"3"},
  {"Name":"user 3","Age":"10","Rank":"2"},
  {"Name":"user 4","Age":"16","Rank":"1"},
  {"Name":"user 5","Age":"14","Rank":"5"},
  {"Name":"user 6","Age":"11","Rank":""}
 ], 
 [
  {"Name":"Person 1","Age":"27","Rank":"6"},
  {"Name":"Person 2","Age":"32","Rank":"3"},
  {"Name":"Person 3","Age":"25","Rank":"2"},
  {"Name":"Person 4","Age":"31","Rank":"4"},
  {"Name":"Person 5","Age":"22","Rank":"1"},
  {"Name":"Person 6","Age":"29","Rank":""}
 ]
]
```

File1:

```
Name,Age,Rank
user 1,12,2
user 2,13,3
user 3,10,2
user 4,16,1
user 5,14,5
user 6,11,7
```

File2:

```
Name,Age,Rank
Person 1,27,6
Person 2,32,3
Person 3,25,2
Person 4,31,4
Person 5,22,1
Person 6,29,5
```

Here is my code.

```js
    import { useState } from "react";
    const LoadFiles = () => {
      const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
      const [processData, setProcessData] = useState(false);
      const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);
    
      const processCSV =   (str, delim = ",") => {
        const headers = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("\n")).split(delim);
        const rows = str.slice(str.indexOf("\n") + 1, str.length - 1).split("\n");
        let nArray = rows.map((row) => {
          const values = row.split(delim);
          const eachObj = headers.reduce((obj, header, i) => {
            obj[header] = values[i];
            return obj;
          }, {});
          return eachObj;
        });
        setAllData([...allData, { nArray }]);
      };
    
      const handleUpload =   () => {
        Array.from(files).forEach(async (file) => {
          const currFile = file;
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = (e) => {
            const text = e.target.result;
            processCSV(text);
          };
          reader.readAsText(currFile);
        });
        setProcessData(true);
      };
    
      const handleChange =   (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setFiles(e.target.files);
      };
    
      return (
        <div id="formWrapper">
          <form id="csv-form">
            <input
              type="file"
              accept=".csv"
              id="csvFile"
              multiple
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            />
            <button
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                handleUpload();
              }}
            >
              Upload your csv
            </button>
          </form>
    
          {processData && console.log(allData)}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default LoadFiles;
```

Here `allData` should hold my final array. Where am I going wrong and how can I fix this?

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-field-fzu81r?file=/src/LoadFiles.js:0-1611).

Comment: What is `[{[file1.csv content]},{[file2.csv content}]`? Please add debugging details: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Updated my question @jabaa

Comment: What does _"currently I see output as"_ mean? How can one variable contain two arrays?

Comment: My bad, should've added a break in between. They are shown as separate arrays. not the same

Comment: I still don't get it. Currently, you see two values in one variable?

Comment: even I'm confused on the same @jabaa. I've added a gif of my current output.

Comment: Do you really need the input element to create a [mcve]? Can't you remove it, create a button instead and use hardcoded values in `setFiles(e.target.files);`?

Comment: Please try: `setAllData(prev => ([...prev, nArray]));`. Also, there are multiple `async` methods; however, none have any `await`.

Comment: @jsN00b, I still see the same result. My bad. Lemme get rid of the `async`s

Comment: Shouldn't `const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);` be inside `processCSV`? Do you expect `allData` to change its value after a call of `setAllData`? `allData` is an empty array the whole time.

Comment: @Rakesh - here's a [working codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-cerf-to55i9): [https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-cerf-to55i9](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-cerf-to55i9). BTW: To `console.log` a state variable, one may use `useEffect` hook (with an appropriate dependency-array).

Comment: Thanks for this @jsN00b, This is what I was looking for :-). And a QQ. in my local the same code is showing multiple console logs unlike in the code sandbox link. Why so?

Comment: In the sandbox I've removed `processedData` flag (or it was named something like that). It was used only to display `console.log(allData)` - and not needed as we can use `useEffect()`. May be that is the reason.

Comment: I am able to fix that thing @jsN00b, Can you please post the codesandbox link as an answer? I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per conversation in the comments, it appears the problem was with below line:

```
setAllData([...allData, { nArray }]);
```

A new codesandbox forked which changed the line like this:

```
setAllData(prev => ([...prev, nArray]));
```

(and made few other changes) seems to have fixed the issue faced.

It is also pertinent to note that `useEffect` may be simple way to `console.log` a state variable. For example, if the state variable we need to log is `allData` (in the above example), then below may be suitable

```
useEffect(
  () => console.log(allData),
  [allData]
);
```

This may be explained like so:

- Whenever `allData` changes (noted in the dependency array of the `useEffect`)
- Execute the `console.log` (the call-back of `useEffect`)

[Codesandbox **Link**](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-cerf-to55i9) with issues fixed: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-cerf-to55i9